# Power / Lock button keeps getting pressed on its own

Tags: nokia-lumia-920

For the last 2 days my 920 is acting weird. The power button keeps getting pressed on its own and phone gets locked / unlocked automatically. This drains my power and interrupts my phone usage.

Any ideas why this happens / what can be done?

Comment: Sounds like a mechanical issue - is there any grit by the button? Do you feel the click when you actually press the button?

Answer (score 1):

Or try changing the back panel.. Faced same problem with Lumia 625 when I ordered a fresh back cover from Amazon, and I ave never used it, since it keep on pressing Power button.

Don't know if Microsoft shipped a faulty product, or the Amazon which is faulty.

Answer (score 0):

It is an mechanical issue.
Faced same with Lumia 720.
Try pressing-unpressing the power button again and again and it will get resolved(worked for me)